# Protobuf.NET using

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, protobuf-net

Need to send some data between managed c# and unmanaged c++. After some research
I tried to use Protobuf.NET.

I'm not sure if I understand functionality of ProtoBuf...

1. Build a type definition in Proto. I need this type definition in both projects c++ and c#
2. Use the command-line tool "protogen.exe" to get an .cs file and .cpp, .h from the type definition
3. Copy the .cs files into my c# project and the .cpp, .h in my c++ solution.

Seems I'm to stupid to to solve this. Here are my problem and questions.

1. Is it possible to define the type in c# to generate the files in for c++ ?
2. Tried to use the command-line tool protogen.exe with the following files

---

test1.proto

> ```
> using ProtoBuf;
> namespace ProtocolBuffers
> {
>     [ProtoContract]
>     class Person
>     {
>         [ProtoMember(1)]
>         public int Id {get;set;}
>         [ProtoMember(2)]
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```

---

test2.proto

```
message Person {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

---

Nothing is working for me. Really tried everything. I put the proto files into the
commandline dir, tried every option to set the dir. How to build them easily ?
The second file is working with standard proto commandline tool for c++ but i need it for c# too. Really need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that protobuf-net is just *one* available implementation for .NET; anyway...

"test1.proto" is not a .proto - it is C#; a .proto is not *required* for use with protobuf-net, but in your interop scenario it is a very good idea. There is VS2010 plugin for this, or alternatively the `protogen` tool that is in the protobuf-net zip:

```
 protogen -i:test2.proto -o:test2.cs
```

This should generate `test2.cs` with the contents:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generated from: test2.proto
namespace test2
{
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Person")]
  public partial class Person : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public Person() {}

    private int _id;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"id", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    public int id
    {
      get { return _id; }
      set { _id = value; }
    }
    private string _name;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true, Name=@"name", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public string name
    {
      get { return _name; }
      set { _name = value; }
    }

    private string _email = "";
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name=@"email", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string email
    {
      get { return _email; }
      set { _email = value; }
    }
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }

}
```

Note that there are additional switches if you want, for example, it to attempt case normalization (so you get `Id`, `Name`, `Email`, etc), or want it to include additional serializer support (`BinaryFormatter`, `DataContractSerializer`, etc)

Comment: I want to generate a similar file from a proto file. Where do I find the protogen tool?

Answer (score 2):

`test1.proto` isn't a valid `.proto` file.

`test2.proto` looks pretty good.  Note that you'll need the compiler from the main protobuf project in order to generate the C++ code, and the compiler from protobuf-net in order to generate the C# code.  I guess most of your problems come from not realizing you need two different compilers (but you feed the same `.proto` file to both).

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know much about ProtoBuf, I do know there is a simpler way of doing this. If the classes above represent the data you are trying to send to C++, just use [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) and serialize your class, then you can output the classes and data to an XML file. Then you can use [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx) or some other XML reader to read in your classes and data. You can even use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to read in the serialized classes.

Comment: umm, no.  Writing parsing code is nowhere near as easy as running the protobuf compiler.

Comment: @Ben -- Who said anything about writing parsing code? .NET and Boost does all the work for you. You don't need to parse anything

Comment: @Ben actually, the "just use Serialization" line amused me... and protobuf is *what*, exactly?

Comment: @icemanind: Boost may do the heavy lifting (conversion of XML to a document model) but you still need to write code to pull data from tags and attributes into C++ objects.  That's non-trivial, and protobuf helps immensely with that.  Not to mention being much more efficient (in both space and computation) than XML.