# Lack of "Line of code" for C# files

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, metrics

I'm using:

> SonarQube 6.7 (build 33306)
>
> SonarC# 7.3.0.5690
>
> sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.2.0.1214-net46

During every analysis I'm getting a lot of warnings:

```
WARNING: WARN: File 'pathToCsharpFile.cs' referenced by the protobuf 'MetricsInfo' does not exist in the analysis context
```

Combinations are for: MetricsInfo, TokenTypeInfo, SymbolReferenceInfo, CopyPasteTokenInfo, etc.

In result, I'm getting no metrics (like `Lines of code`) for cs files (only xml, html, js are calculated)

I'm not 100% sure it's related, but can't find anything else in logs as a potential root cause.

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

In Debug mode I see also a lot of information like:

```
DEBUG: Skipping the ReSharper issue at line 11416 whose file "PathToCsharpFile.cs" is not in SonarQube.
```

I assume it may be connected, but still I don't know how to include/fix it

Comment: I think you're missing or not compiling your protobuf definition into the wire code/model. UPDATE: I think this will get your where you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771713/3225

Comment: @kenny But actually I don't understand this protobuf part since I don't have any protobuf code in my project

Comment: the error message hints at ' referenced by the protobuf ' so I think you perhaps have it included by accident if not intentional.

Comment: @kenny But it's related to every single cs file. It can't be related to protobuf code. Unless sonar is using protobuf in analysis, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: The metrics for all files in the solution are written in a few protobuf files. These files are read during the end step of the analysis and the metrics are reported to SonarQube. If the paths in the protobuf are different than the paths that the Scanner for MSBuild has, you could get this problem. Do you change the current directory between the analysis steps for some reason? Also, I suspect that setting the `sonar.sources` property could lead to the same behavior...

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my findings here as I was also struggling with lines of code metrics being analyzed by SonarQube for my C# .NET project.

**What was happening?**

Due to one of the built-in logic in SonarQube, my main C# project was getting considered as a test project so was getting skipped. Hence lines of code reported for my project was zero. SonarQube analyzes only non-test projects for reporting purposes.

**Why was it happening?**

SonarQube has loads of built-in logic to categorize C# project as a test project or an actual project(which gets shipped to production). You can read about it here on their GitHub page - https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/wiki/Analysis-of-product-projects-vs.-test-projects

We're using [FluentAssertions nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/) in our project. Its description on the nuget page says -

> A very extensive set of extension methods that allow you to more
> naturally specify the expected outcome of a TDD or BDD-style unit
> tests.

It is clear from the description above that it is meant purely for testing purposes. But due to one use case in our product, we had to use it. Little did we know that someday it'll impact SonarQube logic like this.

**What's the solution?**

They've introduced a new tag named **SonarQubeTestProject** which can be put inside the C# project file to treat it as test or non-test project explicitly. More details can be found in this [release announcement](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/dotnet-upcoming-changes-to-how-we-detect-test-projects-in-solution/38955).

**How to do it?**

Here are the steps to achieve this change:

1. Right click on the project icon in solution explorer and then click **Unload Project** in the context menu:

   [image]
2. Right click on the unloaded project icon and click **Edit Project File** in the context menu:

   [image]
3. Place the tag **SonarQubeTestProject** with appropriate value(true/false) inside the **PropertyGroup** tag meant for the build configuration you're targeting. Below project snippet shows the setting done for **Debug** configuration:

   ```html
   <PropertyGroup>
       <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
       <SonarQubeTestProject>false</SonarQubeTestProject>
       <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
       <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
       <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
       .....
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

**Note**: This setting has to be repeated inside each **PropertyGroup** tag meant for other build configurations setup for the project. Projects are usually built with **Release** build configuration in continuous integration (CI) build pipeline. So don't forget to make the change in corresponding **PropertyGroup** tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this command
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe” “D:\Sonar\Source\Proj1.csproj” /t:Rebuild /v:diag

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/